# Pick up tariffs automatically depending on client's name with excel if function

Tags: excel-formula

I have an Excel document with the following setup:

Sheet 1 - A-date, B-client name, C-task description, D-work hours, E-hourly rate, F - total

Sheet 2 - tariffs. A - client name, B - tariff

I want the hourly rate in Sheet 1 pick up a tariff from Sheet 2 automatically, depending on the client name. What would be the right formula?

I tried to use this one but get an Error message

```
=IF(Total Sheet1!B1=Tariffs!A1,Sheet1!K1,Tariffs!B1)
```

[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWX9y.jpg)

[Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3sxI.jpg)

Comment: Instead of using nested `IF`s use [XLOOKUP()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929#:~:text=The%20XLOOKUP%20function%20searches%20a%20range%20or%20an,match.%20%3DXLOOKUP%20%28lookup_value%2C%20lookup_array%2C%20return_array%2C%20%5Bif_not_found%5D%2C%20%5Bmatch_mode%5D%2C%20%5Bsearch_mode%5D%29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the variables inside of " [ ] ", input the range of cells.

`=xlookup( [Client Name], [Range of Client Names], [Range of Tariff Codes],0,0)`

You want to lookup the client name against the list of client names and pull in the tariff code. If you're not on 365, you can use a vlookup as well.

`=vlookup([Client Name], [Range of Clients/Tariffs],2,0)`

The vlookup you'll want to highlight the entire range of clients and tariffs in the second tab at once, and the 2 is the second column containing the tariffs you want. This works because the clients is the leftmost column which is a requirement for vlookups.

Comment: =vlookup(Sheet1!B, [Sheet2!A1:A6/Sheet2!B1:B6],Sheet2!B,0) Something like that?

Comment: Your first condition isn't a cell, and the 3rd condition should be 2. It should look like: `=vlookup(Sheet1!B1, Sheet2!$A$2:$B$6,2,0)`

Comment: could you please take a look again? pressed add comment in the middle of editing it

Comment: I edited my comment to adjust your formula

Comment: doesn't work... I tried it on a simplified table but I cannot insert a picture here in the comment to show

Comment: Doesn't work as in gives a `#N/A!` which can also indicate there simply isn't a match, not that the formula isn't working. You can insert pictures into your post directly. Verify the client name exists in both tables exactly the same way. Also ensure the table you're pulling from includes it in the section `Sheet2!$A$2:$B$6`, so if your range goes to row 1000, you need to adjust the 6 to reflect that. Additionally, make sure B1 is the client name and not the header, it may need to b2, but I can't say the reason without seeing your sheet though, so you'll need to modify formulas until then.

Comment: I added the images in the question post - could you please take a look?

Comment: The first part of the formula should be referencing cell A2, not A1. Right now you have it looking for "Client" in the other table, not "Max".

Comment: Happy that we could reach a solution.